# Issues when applying a mathematical operation to a column of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numexpr

In Jupyter Notebook, I am trying to divide a column of a dataframe by 10, but this is the error that I am getting:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[20, 20.25], 'B':[70, 41]})
df['A'] = df['A']/10

      8 try:
      9     import numexpr as ne
---> 10     ver = LooseVersion(ne.__version__)
     11     _NUMEXPR_INSTALLED = ver >= LooseVersion(_MIN_NUMEXPR_VERSION)
     12     _NUMEXPR_VERSION = ver

AttributeError: module 'numexpr' has no attribute '__version__'
```

Anybody knows why this is happening and how to fix it. I suspect is a pandas issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this by upgrading ipython and the pandas and numexpr versions from the ipython.

```
pip3.6 install --upgrade ipython    
pip3.6 install --upgrade pandas
pip3.6 install --upgrade numexpr
```